# Android notifications not received - Oreo vs Nougat

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-7.0-nougat, android-8.0-oreo

I am trying to run a Notification example that I downloaded from Google.
I edit it to make it minimal - then compile it and it works OK.

Here is my code:

```
private void test_notifications() {
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification n1 =  new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentText("setContentText1")
            .setContentTitle("setContentTitle2")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .build();

    mNotificationManager.notify(123, n1);
}
```

I then created a new project and pasted this code into it.
I do not get notifications ...
I think - not sure at all - that the reason is:
The project that I downloaded from Google is using  compileSdkVersion 25
While my Studio generates compileSdkVersion 26

Now my phone is running Android 'O'
So I suspect - not sure - that if I want notifications on 'O' I have two alternatives:
1) Compile with 26 and implement the new channel.
2) Compile with 25.


My first approach was to add a channel
I copied the channel code from google site:

```
private void test_notifications() {

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// The id of the channel.
    String id = "my_channel_01";
// The user-visible name of the channel.
    CharSequence name = "My Channel";
// The user-visible description of the channel.
    String description = "my description";
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
    NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, importance);
// Configure the notification channel.
    mChannel.setDescription(description);
    mChannel.enableLights(true);
// Sets the notification light color for notifications posted to this
// channel, if the device supports this feature.
    mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
    mChannel.enableVibration(true);
    mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);



    // NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification n1 =  new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentText("setContentText1")
            .setContentTitle("setContentTitle2")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setChannelId("my_channel_01")
            .build();

    mNotificationManager.notify(123, n1);
}
```

Still - no notifications.
Any idea?

My other approach is to try and build my app like google did - linked with the *.25 libs instead of the *.26 libs

I could not set Studio to use older libs.
Amy idea?
Or should I uninstall Android Studio and install an older version?
Thanks
Ori

Comment: NotificationCompat.Builder(Context context) is deprecated in Android Oreo. Try using NotificationCompat.Builder(Context context, String channelId) instead.

Comment: Thank you. 
I found Google's example at - https://github.com/googlesamples/android-NotificationChannels
- Ori